# How can I ignore @types when creating a production build for a react typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, typescript-typings

I have a typescript React project using CRA that uses some libraries and their types. e.g. pako and @types/pako.

When deploying this to production, I have a script that runs in a container that installs the dependencies, runs `npm run build` and pushes the build folder to an S3 bucket.

I would like to ignore the @types libraries when doing this, to make the deployment faster. I have placed the @types in devDependencies, and ran `npm i --production` and then `npm run build` but my build fails with the following message:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '<<module>>'. 
'....../node_modules/<<module>>/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Not sure if this is possible, but how can I successfully ignore the @types dependencies for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place "@types" in "devDependencies" in package.json:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/pako
```

Use "npm ci" instead of "npm i --production" for deployment:

```
# Clear existing dependencies
rm -rf node_modules

# Install only production dependencies (excluding @types)
npm ci

# Build the project
npm run build

# Continue with your deployment steps (e.g., pushing to S3 bucket)
```